# Connection refused by Domino Server

Tags: pentaho, lotus-domino, lotus

We use Pentaho to generate reports and dashboards with data of a Domino Server using a JDBC connector, and **they were both working fine**, but few weeks ago we noticed our Pentaho reports didn't work. This is the message we get from the console:

```
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class com.ibm.domino.domsql.DomSQLDriver)
Error while connecting to the remote server at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:579)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:450)
... 120 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while connecting to the remote server
at com.ibm.domino.domsql.DomSQLDriver.createRemoteConnection(DomSQLDriver.java:197)
at com.ibm.domino.domsql.DomSQLDriver.connect(DomSQLDriver.java:122)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:561)
... 121 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: mydomain.org; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.domsql.DomSQLDriver.loadDriverFromRegistry(DomSQLDriver.java:202)
at com.ibm.domino.domsql.DomSQLDriver.createRemoteConnection(DomSQLDriver.java:187)
... 125 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211) at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 131 more

Custom URL : jdbc:domsql://mydomain.org/database.nsf/data
Custom Driver Class:com.ibm.domino.domsql.DomSQLDriver
```

We think there is something in the Domino configuration which is refusing the connection. The Domino version is 9.0.1FP5.

We have uninstalled OpenSocial Component and then we installed it again, but this is not the solution because DOTS was working and is still working properly. We have tried another different ideas, but nothing works.

If anyone can help us, it'll be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!!

**Edit:**

We are still getting this error. We tried many different solutions but nothing works. The JVM (in client and server) policy is set to allow all:

```
grant{
  all permission java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

We have checked the Domino server configuration document but we don't find anything bad that could be the reason of issue. Same trying the connection with dbVisualizer, connection refused. We reinstalled the server, all the fix packs, uninstall and install OpenSocial Component... nothing works. This is frustrating, so please if anyone can help us we will appreciate it so much.

Comment: It might be an authentication problem.  Make sure the NotesID being used to access the Domino db is still valid and has access.

Comment: "Connection refused" is a network error. It occurs before authentication can possibly be checked.

Comment: I had already checked the notes ID and also I had created a new one, but this was OK, so I think as Richard has said that there is a network issue. Richard, both servers are located on the same machine. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? I'm sorry but I can't give you more info, we don't know why it has stopped working.

Comment: Is the connection over SSL? If so, is certificate expired?  Perhaps the firewall is blocking the connection -- have permissions for programs/ports changed?

Comment: Yes, the connection is over SSL. I'm looking for issues with the certificate and I will update you with news as I find something wrong here, thank you! If someone has any other suggestions would be fantastic too!

Comment: I think this is something related with the JVM security, I'm looking for some information about this, because I remember that I had to change something when we started with Pentaho. If someone has any idea, I'm still trying to get it up, so it would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have finally solved it uninstalling the Domino Server and then installing it again.